# identifying concavitie(s) and inflection(s) for $f(x) = (x-1)^{1/3} + (x+1)^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus

As the title states I have to find the inflections and concavities of

$f(x) = (x-1)^{1/3} + (x+1)^{1/3}$

Since the second derivative

$f''(x) \ne 0 $ this should not have a inflection.

However upon looking at the formula I noticed that the inflection instead was identified using the original function $f(x)$

Where $x=0$ there apparently is a inflection. How did he figure out that from the first function, what's the relationship between the first function and it's second derivative? I would (evidently) stop after $f''(x) \ne 0 $ and conclude that there were no concavities. And all x-intersects are not necessarily inflection-points.

Many thanks whomever might help me!

Comment: A twice differentiable function does have inflection points where its second derivative equal 0.

Comment: How does $f(-x)$ compare with $f(x) \; ?$

Comment: @WillJagy Well $f(-x)$ and $f(x)$ do have different signs, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Or at points where the derivative doesn’t exist, here $x=\pm1$.